# Finding eigenvalues of $D + \alpha v v^*{}$ with $D$ being a diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I know how to find eigenvalues of an $n \times n$ Hermitian matrix
$$H = I + \alpha vv^{*},$$
where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, $v \in \mathbb{C}^n$ is a unit length vector. We can write
\begin{align}
(I + \alpha vv^{*})x &= \lambda x \\
\alpha vv^{*}x &= (\lambda-1) x.
\end{align}
The LHS of the equation has a rank one projector $\alpha vv^{*}$ with an eigenvector $v$ and eigenvalues $\alpha$ and $0$. Therefore, we can see that $x = v$ and $\lambda = \alpha+1$. The rest of the eigenvalues of $H$ equal 1.

I would like to know if it is possible to find analytically at least two eigenvalues for a slightly more general case:
$$H = D + \alpha vv^{*},$$
where $D$ is a real diagonal matrix and $v$ is not an eigenvector of $D$.

Comment: Using the same notation for matrices and integers is confusing.  Use `{\bf H}` instead.